# jQuery add ID increment to .html() appending on input onchange and refresh onchange value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize for the wordy title but I haven't found a solution to my problem yet. I am a newbie with jQuery and web development so any guidance would be appreciated.

I have a `<input>` that allows user to enter a value (number) of how many rows of a set of input fields they want populated. Here's my example:

```
<div id="form">
<input id="num" name="num" type="text" />
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="form2">
<form action="" method="post" class="form_main">
    <div class="data">
        <div class="item">
            <input id="name" name="name[]" type="text" placeholder="name" /><br/>
            <input id="age" name="age[]" type="text" placeholder="age" /><br/>
            <input id="city" name="city[]" type="text" placeholder="city" /><br/>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My jQuery:

```
<script>
var itemNum = 1;
$("#num").on("change", function() {
    var count = this.value; 
    var item = $(".item").parent().html();
    //item.attr('id', 'item' + itemNum);

    for(var i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
        itemNum++;
        $(".data").append(item);            
    }
})
</script>
```

I'm having problems adding an ID `item+itemNum` increment to `<div class="item">`... `item.attr()` didn't work. It doesn't append once I added that line of code.

Also, how can I get it so that once a user enters a number that populates rows of input fields, that if they change that number it will populate that exact number instead of adding to the already populated rows? Sorry if this doesn't make any sense. Please help!

Comment: Difficult to understand exactly what you want.  Is the intention that if the user enters '3', then `<div class="item">` and its child inputs are duplicated 2 times and added to to `<div class="data">`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want the contents in `<div class="item">` and when it is populated each div will have an id increment. So like `<div class="item" id="item2"> ... id="item3">... etc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/y5z7V/3/)**

```
var itemNum = 1;
$("#num").on("change", function() {

$('.data div').slice(1).remove();  //code for removing previously populated elements.
var count = this.value;
console.log(count);
var item; 
//item.attr('id', 'item' + itemNum);
var i;
for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    item = $("#item0").clone().attr('id','item'+itemNum);


    //prevent duplicated ID's
    item.children('input[name="name[]"]').attr('id','name'+itemNum);      
    item.children('input[name="age[]"]').attr('id','age'+itemNum);   
    item.children('input[name="city[]"]').attr('id','city'+itemNum);

    itemNum++;
    $(".data").append(item);            
}
})
```

Use **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** instead of html()

Comment: @shaunakde, when I use clone, it appends like 2x the amount. If entered 2, it clones 2 of item2, if entered 3 it clones 3 of item3.

Comment: @StormParker then change it to `for(var i = 2;`

Comment: This will result in duplicate ID's for inputs, so you will then need to update the html of the clone.

Comment: Updated the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/y5z7V/1/)** for your comment @Storm Parker..working on duplicate id's now.

Comment: @shaunakde Thank you! What about when the users enter a new number, it populates the exact number of row instead of adding to the already populated rows?

Comment: Do you want to clear previously populated rows when the user enter new number?

Comment: @shaunakde yes, to have it clear and add the newly entered number. Right now it just adds to the previously populated rows.

Comment: Updated the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/y5z7V/2/)** for duplicate ids issue.

Comment: Final update to the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/y5z7V/3/)** Previously populated items cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var itemNum = 1,
    item = $(".data .item").parent().html();;
$("#num").on("change", function () {
    var count = +this.value;
    if (itemNum < count) {
        while (itemNum < count) {
            itemNum++;
            $(item).attr('id', 'item' + itemNum).appendTo('.data')
        }
    } else {
        itemNum = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $('.data .item').slice(itemNum).remove();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vyX7r/)

Comment: this works too! How about the refreshing of values on the first input that users enter the numbers in?

Comment: @StormParker sorry, refreshing what number?